# Dependency in Maven

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, maven-dependency-plugin

I am really new to maven. I am bit confused about the dependency feature. I know that I can add dependency in the pom file like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

What does this actually mean? Does it mean that I dont need to import the slf4j jar files into my project? If so how does my project get access to those libraries?

I have read about dependency from [maven site](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) but didnt help me much.

Can some one explain it in a simpler way.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nutshell: It means your project has a dependency on slf4j, version 1.6.1.

Furthermore:

- If you build your project with Maven (or your IDE is Maven-aware), you don't have to do anything else in order to use slf4j. (Aside from normal source-code considerations, like a reasonable `import` statement, etc.)
- slf4j v. 1.6.1 will be retrieved from a default Maven repository to your local repository, meaning...
- ... `~/.m2/repository` is your repository. slf4j will be put in `$M2_HOME/org/slf4j/$(artifactId}/1.6.1` and will include (in general) a jar file, a pom file, and a hash file.
- Slf4j's *dependencies* will be downloaded into your local repository as well.
- Dependencies of *those* dependencies will be downloaded ad infinitum/ad nauseum. (The source of "first use of a library downloads the internet" jokes if there are a lot of dependencies; not the case for slf4j.) This is "transitive dependency management"--one of Maven's original purposes.

Answer (score 2):

If you were not using maven, you would manually download and use the dependencies that you needed for your project.  You would probably place them in a lib folder and specify this location in your IDE as well as your build tool.

maven manages these dependencies for you. You specify the dependency your project needs in the prescribed format and maven downloads them for you from the internet and manages them. When building your project, maven knows where it has placed these dependencies and uses them. Most IDEs also know where these dependencies are, when they discover that it is a maven project.

Why is this a big deal?  Typically most open source libraries release newer versions on a regular basis.  If your project uses these, then each time a newer version is needed, you would need to manually download it and manage it. More importantly, each dependency, in turn may have other dependencies (called transitive dependency).  If you do not use maven, you would need to identify, download and manage these transitive dependencies as well.

It becomes complex the more such dependencies that your project uses.  It is possible that two dependencies end up using different versions of a dependency common to them.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of servers on the internet that host artifacts (jars) that you can download as part of a maven build. You can add dependencies like you show above to describe what jars you need in order to build your code. When maven goes to build, it will contact one of these servers and download the jar to your computer and place it in a local repository usually

```
${user_home}/.m2/repository
```

The servers that maven contacts must be configured in your maven project pom file, under a section like

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

The prototypical server can be seen at [repo1.maven.org](http://repo1.maven.org)

The nice thing about maven is that if a jar you list is needed, it will pull not only that jar, but any jars that that jar needs. Obviously, since you are pulling the jars to your machine, it only downloads them when it can't find them on your machine, thus not slowing down your build everytime (just the first time).

Answer (score 1):

When compiling your project, Maven will download the corresponding .jar file from a repository, usually the central repository (you can configure different repositories, either for mirroring or for your own libraries which aren't available on the central repositories).

If your IDE know about Maven, it will parse the `pom` and either download the dependencies itself or ask Maven to do so. Then it will open the dependencies' jars, and this is how you get autocompletion: the IDE "imports" the jars for you behind the scenes.

The repository contains not only the ".jar" file for the dependency, but also a ".pom" file, which describes its dependencies. So, maven will recursively download its dependencies, and you will get all the jars you need to compile your software.

Then, when you will try to run your software, you will have to tell the JVM where to find these dependencies (ie, you have to put them on the class path).

What I usually do is copy the dependencies to a `target/lib/` directory, so it is easy to deploy the software and to launch it. To do so, you can use the `maven-dependency-plugin`, which you specify in the `<build>`:

```
<build>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</build>
```